# Cannot append image with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I currently have a code working where i can add a class based on the url of a page using jquery. However I would like add an image to a div instead of just adding a class. I'm not as proficient in java-script as I could be but I think there is probably a pretty simple solution.  The code that doesn't work is

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('Locate_an_eyecare_professional') > -1) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = '~/Content/Images/Template 5A Filmstrip.jpg" />';



    }
```

the code that works right now that I dont want to use is

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('Locate_an_eyecare_professional') > -1) {
        var $body = $('body');

        $body.addClass('campaign');


    }
```

How can apply what I do know that works to what I am trying to get to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for some reason you don't want to use jQuery for this part, you just need to append the element to the body of the html document (or wherever you want it to end up) like so:

### Javascript Code

```js
if (window.location.href.indexOf('Locate_an_eyecare_professional') > -1) {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.className = 'img-responsive'
  img.src = '~/Content/Images/Template 5A Filmstrip.jpg';
  body.appendChild(img);
}
```

Comment: This works very well! There is only one problem. This is a responsive website. So i must use the class img-responsive for all of my images to display properly. How can I add a class to this javascript code that works so well?

Comment: I edited it with a way to add a class by it's name. If this works for you please accept it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `<img>` to any element using the jQuery `.append()` function in the following way:

```
var imageToAppend = '<img src="http://example.com/img.png" height="200" width="200"/>';
$('#myElementId').append(imageToAppend); //This will append you HTML to the div with id "myElementId"
```

You can read more about this here: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Happy coding! =]

Comment: I tried that but nothing shows up.Here is my whole code now.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        if (window.location.href.indexOf('Locate_an_eyecare_professional') > -1) {
            var imageToAppend = '<img src="~/Content/Images/Template 5A Filmstrip.jpg" />';
       
    
            $('#myElementId').append(imageToAppend);
            
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>



    <div id="myElementId" style="height:800px;">




    </div>

Comment: Notice that your code needs to be in a `$(document).ready(function(){ //Your code goes here});`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the element where you need to append (prepend) the image element so the code will look something like:

```
$("base element selector").append(img);
```

but you need to consider that the address of the image source may not be correct from the browser point of view - consider the page is hosted in application like `http://server.com//applicationgroup/applicationroot/Content/Images/.....jpg` may not be pointed with `~/Content/Images/.....jpg` you rather need to translate the address to the full server address on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just had to remove "~" from:

```html
<img src="~/assets/icons/ic_chevron2.svg" class="rot-90" />
```

resulting in:

```html
<img src="/assets/icons/ic_chevron2.svg" class="rot-90" />
```